# How to host blazor Application and Dotnet Api Both?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-blazor

If I host my asp dotnet project only at myasp.Net which provides free hosting for 1 month then it hosted successfully and work fine.but now i have two projects in which separate Api project and blazor in same solution.Means i have two projects Blazor server and 2nd Dotnet api which blazor consume.Now i don't now how to publish both projects on single site which i create let say on Myasp.Net

Comment: See the following short article of mine - https://shauncurtis.github.io/articles/Blazor-AllinOne.html.  It shows how to host a Server, WASM and API site on a single web site

Comment: Thanx @MrCakaShaunCurtis for response but unfortunately it don't resolve my problem.

Comment: @Asif Maybe you can host it on your subfolder, like yourdomain.com/blazor.